# Shortcut for joining two lines

Tags: visual-studio-code

What's the keyboard shortcut for joining two lines in VS Code?

If the cursor is anywhere in the first line of

```
    f(foo,
      bar)
```

then when I hit the shortcut, I want to get

```
    f(foo, bar)
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Visual Studio Code now comes with a default key binding for joining lines, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>.

You can find all keyboard shortcuts under `Preferences > Open Keyboard Shortcuts`.

You can overwrite it using the UI or by providing a different key combination for the command `editor.action.joinLines` in `keybindings.json`.

Comment: Shortcurt not set by default on VS Code 1.34

Comment: This is cool, but I wish it would join the lines without spaces between the content.

Comment: Errr, no it doesn't - CTRL + J  is set to View:Toggle Panel by default

Comment: What is `preferences > open keyboard shorcuts`? This answer is surprisingly misleading for an upvoted accepted answer.

Comment: @EugZol on a Macbook it's the menu `Code>Preferences>Keyboard Shortcuts`

Comment: On Windows `File>Preferences>Keyboard Shortcuts`

Answer (score 34):

Press `F1`, and type `Join Lines`. By default there is no key bindings to it yet, but you can easily set it under `Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts`, then search for `Join Lines` and set a shortcut.

Comment: or type jl rather than the whole words to speed things up considerably

Answer (score 8):

You can simply:

- Select the lines to be joined.
- Hit `Ctrl+Shift+P` or `F1`.
- Type `join lines`.

Comment: or type just the two letters jl instead to save time

Answer (score 7):

Since the best way is already answered I'm just adding an alternative.

If you want to work with defaults you can hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> while caret is at the end of the first line.

Works with multi-select too if you want to join multiple lines.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how much clutter you have in your , try the following "keypress sequence" (you *must have focus in an open editor tab for this to work*<sup>1</sup>, and make sure to have your cursor/lines selected before doing this):

- <kbd><kbd>Ctrl+Shift+P</kbd>  <kbd>J</kbd><kbd>L</kbd></kbd>   <sup>2</sup>

If your Command Palette ends up showing a clash of non-`Join Lines` entries when you finish typing, you may have to end up typing instead<sup>3</sup>:

- <kbd><kbd>Ctrl+Shift+P</kbd>  <kbd>J</kbd><kbd>O</kbd><kbd>I</kbd><kbd>N</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> <kbd>L</kbd></kbd>
- <kbd><kbd>Ctrl+Shift+P</kbd>  <kbd>J</kbd><kbd>O</kbd><kbd>I</kbd><kbd>N</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> <kbd>L</kbd><kbd>I</kbd></kbd>
- ...
- <kbd><kbd>Ctrl+Shift+P</kbd>  <kbd>J</kbd><kbd>O</kbd><kbd>I</kbd><kbd>N</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> <kbd>L</kbd><kbd>I</kbd><kbd>N</kbd><kbd>E</kbd><kbd>S</kbd></kbd>
- ...Manually select from the Palette using down arrow or mouse <sup>4</sup>

---

In case you're thinking about setting your own keybind (since it is unset by default in Windows), here are the other Commands that have a keybind associated with them containing a <kbd>J</kbd> <sup>5</sup>:

| Command | Keybinding | When |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `workbench.action.search.toggleQueryDetails` | <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> | `inSearchEditor || searchViewletFocus` |
| View: Toggle Panel | <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> | --- |
| Unfold All | <kbd><kbd>Ctrl+K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl+J</kbd></kbd> | `editorTextFocus && foldingEnabled` |
| Notebook: Join With Previous Cell | <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> | `notebookEditorFocused` |
| Notebook: Join With Next Cell | <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> | `editorTextFocus && foldingEnabled` |

I suggest using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>if you end up going this route, since it doesn't seem to clash with existing defaults and is similar to what people are already used to.

---

Alternatively, if you tend to use a different text editor or IDE,

[**File** > **Preferences** > **Keymaps**] (<kbd><kbd>Ctrl+K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl+M</kbd></kbd>) offers a selection of alternative keymaps (these are extensions, which must be *installed*), including (as of now, sorted by current rating):

- IntelliJ IDEA (by *Keisuke Kato*)
- Sublime Text (by *Microsoft*)
- Atom (by *Microsoft*)
- Eclipse (by *Alphabot Security*)
- Visual Studio (by *Microsoft*)
- Delphi (by *Alessandro Fragnani*)
- Notepad++ (by *Microsoft*)
- Vim (by *vscodevim*)
- Emacs (by *hirosun*)

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>  In other words, don't *be* in a "non-editor" window like **Settings** or **Keyboard Shortcuts**</sup>
<sup><sup>2</sup> Alternatively, Command Palette can also be opened by selecting [**View** > **Command Palette...**] instead of <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+P</kbd></sup>
<sup><sup>3</sup>  This could occur due to having 3rd-party Commands containing the letters `j` and `l`. Command Palette can also be found alternatively by selecting [**View** > **Command Palette...**]</sup>
<sup><sup>4</sup>  Hopefully you don't end up with this case.</sup>
<sup><sup>5</sup>  These are all listed under [**File** > **Preferences** > **Keyboard Shortcuts**] (<kbd><kbd>Ctrl+K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl+S</kbd></kbd>)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for such a fantastic rich answer, can't believe noone has upvoted it before. I've always wanted to know how exactly this all works, wonderful!